# An error in the HTML "upgrade-insecure-requests"

Tags: html, bootstrap-4

The Content Security Policy 'upgrade-insecure-requests' was delivered via a  element outside the document's , which is disallowed. The policy has been ignored.

I got this while adding bootstrap in balzor. please anyone can help.

I added

`<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="upgrade-insecure-requests" />`

Comment: Could you post your entire `<head>` tag?

Answer (score 0):

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="block-all-mixed-content">
```

try to add this meta tag inside your head tag. and if still getting the same issue then share a screenshot of the error.